# query rule sharepoint search

Tags: query-string, regex, search-query

```
((^(?!(([\d-\.\s\(\)+]*([a-df-su-wyzA-DF-SU-WYZ]+|[tT]|[eE](?![xX][tT])|[xX][a-zA-Z]+))|(\d{1,3}$)|((\+|00|0)(\d+)$)))(")?(((\+|00|0)|(?=(\d*\s*\()))[0]*(?<country>\d+))?[\.\s-]?(\(?(?<area>\d+)\)?)?[\.\s-]?(?<number1>\d+)?[\.\s-]?(?<number2>\d+)\s?([eExXtT]*\.?\s?(?<extension>\d+))?(")?)$)|(^(?![tT]|[eE](?![xX][tT])|[xX][a-zA-Z]+)[eExXtT]+\.?\s?(?<extension>\d+)?$)|(^(?=(\+|00|0)(\d{4,-})$)(")?(\+|00|0)(?<area>\d+)(")?$)
```

Does anyone know what this regular expression means.It is a query rule from my sharepoint site search

Comment: Which rule is it associated with?

Comment: a telephone number